# How to test a SQL Procedure with type objects

Tags: sql-server

A SQL Server procedure has parameters are :-

```
Create Procedure Inspect(@ID int, @TBL UserType readonly) as...
```

UserType is defined as :-

```
Create Type UserType ( Id int, Type varchar(20), UID int)
```

My question is how do I debug in SQL, how can I pass UserType into an EXEC command.  THere is no example with the code?

```
Exec Inspect 9,
```

Comment: Google “table valued parameter” for examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an example:

```
Create Type UserType AS TABLE (Id int, [Type] varchar(20), [UID] int) 

CREATE PROCEDURE Inspect(@ID int, @TBL UserType readonly) 
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM @TBL
END

DECLARE @tbl UserType
INSERT INTO @tbl(Id,Type,UID) SELECT sv.number,sv.type,sv.low FROM master.dbo.spt_values AS sv 
EXEC Inspect @ID=1,@TBL=@tbl
```

Comment: Please delete one of your answers, i'll approve the other as they're duplicate.  Appreciate  the help.